# How to select first or last value from phone numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a TABLE

```
select * from TEL_NUM

   +----+---------+----------|
   | id |  TEL_NUM |REG_DATE | 
   +----+---------+----------+
   |  1 |   6111   |20150101 |
   |  2 |   6112   |20150102 |
   |  3 |   6112   |20150102 |
   |  4 |   6112   |20150103 |
   |  5 |   6111   |20150103 |
   |  6 |   6113   |20150103 |
   |  7 |   6113   |20150104 |
   |  8 |   6113   |20150105 |
   |  9 |   6113   |20150106 |
   +----+---------+----------+
```

In my case I have to display record just 3 rows because there is just 3 tel number with different date.
How to select one by one tel number? Should I use `max` date?
 **I need how many times they called on each different date for all the dates in table. Like this information:**

> 6111 called once on 2015 01 01 6112 called 2 times on 2015 01 02 6112
>   called once on 2015 01 03 6111 called once on 2015 01 03 6113 called
>   once 2015 01 03 6113 called once 2015 01 04 6113 called once 2015 01
>   05 6113 called once 2015 01 06

Comment: Easier to answer if you specify the columns and output you're expecting. Group by Date/Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you need. Just the phone numbers? Then use SELECT DISTINCT. The phone number and the most recent reg_date for each phone number? Then GROUP BY tel_num and in the SELECT clause, include MAX(reg_date). If neither, then what?

EDIT:  Based on further input from OP - he needs caller TEL_NUM, the REG_DATE, and how many times that caller called on that date. This is a job for the aggregate function COUNT(*).

```
select   tel_num, reg_date, count(*) as cnt
from     table_name
group by tel_num, reg_date
;
```

You may need to add `ORDER BY TEL_NUM, REG_DATE`  (or if you need it the other way around, `ORDER BY REG_DATE, TEL_NUM`).

Comment: Thank you almost solved I understood. I need how many called they are.

Comment: It is still not clear. Do you need the phone number, and how many times they called.... when? Do you need the total number of times they called? Or do you need how many times they called on each different date? And if so, for which date(s)...  just the most recent date for each phone number, or for all the dates in the table? If for all the dates, the result will be more than 3 rows. Please show desired OUTPUT in your original post (calculated by hand, not through a query) - what should be the result of the query?

Comment: Yes I need how many times they called on each different date for all the dates in table. For example: 6111 called - once on 2015 01 01, 6112 called 2 times on 2015 20150102 and once on 20150103

Please I need it immediately. Thank you

Comment: @user2801618 - I edited my reply to address what you put in the comment.

Comment: May I use like this count(tel_num), count(reg_date) ? 
Thanks indeed. I just used your query ;)

Comment: Why would you count tel_num and reg_date? What is the business requirement for that?

Comment: select   tel_num, reg_date, count(*) as cnt
group by tel_num, reg_date
Union all
select 'SUM' tel_num, COUNT(cnt)
from table_name   am I right?

Comment: You are stating what solutions are going through your mind, instead of what problem you are trying to solve. "SUM" is how you do it, but WHAT are you trying to do? If you need to add a total row, to count over all phone numbers or over all dates (or both), then take a look at `GROUP BY ROLLUP` - you only need to change the GROUP BY clause, nothing else. (The ROLLUP extension to GROUP BY does exactly that.)

Comment: Yes. Exactly I solved my problem 100%  I appreciate you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need the `id`, here's one option using `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
   select id, tel_num, reg_date, 
       row_number() over (partition by tel_num order by regdate desc) rn
   from tel_num
) t
where rn = 1
```

---

If you just need the `tel_num` and `reg_date`, then you can just use `max`:

```
select tel_num, max(reg_date)
from tel_num
group by tel_num
```

Btw -- in general I wouldn't name columns the same as the table...